# going back to directory

Tags: powershell

My current directory is

```
C:/users/admin/temp
```

Next, I navigate to

```
C:/users/admin/temp/1/2
```

How do I get back to `temp` without using `pushd` command at temp and just go to `temp` with one command without going home or doing `cd ~`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location) and [`Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/pop-location) instead of `cd` (aka, [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location)).

Or, if you just want to traverse up the directory heirarchy two levels, you can use `cd ..\..`.

Comment: Interestingly I cannot set `cd ..\..` as an alias!

Comment: @MarkusL Yes, PowerShell aliases can't have arguments like that, but functions can.  Just type `Function up2 { cd ..\.. }` to declare it and `up2` to use it.  Or see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69490652/5405967) below for a more versatile "up" function (and back/forward functions too).

Answer (score 7):

With `Powershell Core 6.2.2` or later you can do `cd -` to navigate to your previous directory.

`cd` is the alias for `Set-Location`. Adding paramerter `+ or -` goes forward or backward through your location history.

[Powershell Docs - Set-Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: +1 This is the best answer for modern users.  Also see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69490652/5405967) below about taking `cd -`/`cd +` further.

Comment: You have drastically improved my quality of life - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A useful tool is [z](https://github.com/vincpa/z). You could type `z temp`, and z would take you back to the temp folder. It uses some guesswork to work out where it thinks you want to go to, using an algorithm based on frequency and recency, but it almost always guesses correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in commands `cd +`/`cd -` are great but kind of a pain to use repeatedly.  Here are some wrappers to make them easier/faster to use:

```
Function b([int]$n = 1) {
    foreach ($i in 1..$n) { cd - }
}

Function f([int]$n = 1) {
    foreach ($i in 1..$n) { cd + }
}

# runs "cd -"
b

# runs "cd +; cd +; cd +"
f 3
```

And here is a function for going up one or multiple levels (in one step):

```
Function u([int]$n = 1) {
    cd (@('..') * $n -join '/')
}

# runs "cd .."
u

# runs "cd ../../.."
u 3
```

And the `pushd`/`popd` aliases are too long for my taste:

```
Set-Alias pu Push-Location
Set-Alias po Pop-Location
```

Answer (score 1):

I like how zsh does it.  You can do `cd -2` to go to the second entry in the directory stack.  http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_6.html

This is as close as I can get in pwsh, after using pushd a few times:

```
$a = pwd -stack
cd $a.toarray()[1]
```

I like to alias cd to pushd in $profile.  Then I type popd when I want to go back.

```
set-alias cd pushd -option allscope
```

I'm liking this method lately, "cd-" without a space in between:

```
set-alias cd pushd -option allscope
set-alias cd- popd -option allscope
```